# Jira worklog per project

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

We would like to integrate Jira with our local reporting application. I would like to ask whether is possible to get the worklog per Jira project. I mean whether I could retrieve all of the logged times for a specific project and a specific date range. 
Another solution could be to retrieve all of the users assigned to the project and their logged times for a certain period. F.e.

- Retrieve all of the users assigned to project xy
- Retrieve the work log for user John Doe for February (total hours worked and in the best case also the tasks he was working on)

I am quite new in Jira and the its rest api, therefore each advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [rest end point](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/0.4/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/SearchRestClient.html) to find out what are issues of project with using jql query like:

```
project = PROJECT_KEY
```

You need to use [SearchResult#getTotal](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/0.4/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/domain/SearchResult.html#getTotal%28%29) to find out how many issues actually given project contains and later call N number of times [searchJql](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/0.4/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/SearchRestClient.html#searchJql%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.ProgressMonitor%29) with appropriate startAt value. When you have issue keys for a particular project you need to use [getIssue](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/0.4/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/IssueRestClient.html#getIssue%28java.lang.String,%20com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.ProgressMonitor%29) to retrieve an Issue object which have a method [getWorklogs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/0.4/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/domain/Issue.html#getWorklogs%28%29). When you fetch worklogs of issue you need to iterate over them and collect values you are interested in. Each worklog object have methods:

1. getAuthor()
2. getMinutesSpent()
3. getUpdateDate()

With this data you can achieve all of your goals. You will have information who, worked how long, on which issues and so on.